# Can't run go permission denied?

Tags: go, raspberry-pi, permission-denied

```
david@raspberrypi:~ $ go env

-bash: /usr/bin/go: Permission denied
```

this is my bash.rc

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go

$HOME/.bashrc 

export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

if i run ls-lah in my david@raspberry pi, i get the following:

```
david@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -lah 
total 28K 
drwxr-xr-x 3 david david 4.0K Mar  2 22:20 . 
drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root  4.0K Mar  2 20:03 ..
-rw------- 1 david david 3.1K Mar  2 21:48 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  220 Mar  2 20:03 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 3.6K Mar  2 22:15 .bashrc 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 david root    11 Mar  2 21:31 go -> /usr/lib/go 
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david 4.0K Mar  2 20:25 .nano
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  675 Mar  2 20:03 .profile
```

Comment: 0755 works for me on Debian

Comment: care to elaborate?

Comment: I am using webmin to admin the server. Just select the go executeable and set the permissions to 0755. And the executable will start. I guess this will apply on Raspian as well.

Comment: how do i get rid of this? lrwxrwxrwx 1 david root    11 Mar  2 21:31 go -> /usr/lib/go 
i assume that is screwing up everything

Comment: Find the go executable and set chmod? https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx means it is a symbolic link. you can just run `unlink go` to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the user you're logged in as doesn't have permissions to run go.

To find that out, run the following

```
$ which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go

$ ls -l $(which go)
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12896684 Jan 24 01:28 /usr/local/go/bin/go
```

From the above we know that the owner is `root` and group owner is `wheel`.

Now run `echo $USER` to see if who is logged in user.

Since you're getting permission denied to run go as `$USER`, you may want to add the user into the group mentioned in `ls -l`. So, run the below.

```
$ usermod -aG $USER wheel
```

And reboot the system! Then try `go env` again to see if it works.

-a is for append
-G is for which groups to append

[usermod docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/usermod.8.html)

Remember wheel is the group owner that I got while running `ls -l`. Yours might be different.
This usermod command is for ubuntu. In your case, it is raspberry pi so raspbian OS. Find out the correct options as it changes from OS to OS.

Comment: when i do sudo apt-get install golang, i get: golang is already the newest version (2:1.7~5).